# Exchange - Get capacity of resource with a soap query

Tags: soap, resources, exchange-server, capacity

I would like to know if it's possible to retrieve the capacity of a resource with a soap query.

I have the eqivalent in the power shell command but not the soap query.

Shell command equivalent:
Get-Mailbox "Salle 1" | Select ResourceCapacity

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about any direct operation but you can find that
user mailbox is full or not by using **GetMailTips Operation**
which will return an xml which contain  node

ref :- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877060%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx

I hope, i understand your requirement.

Comment: Thanks but it's not good for me. ResourceCapacity is a parameter about the number of seat in room. I'm looking for to retrieve parameters about a exchange resource with a soap query.